# ASP.NET MVC - Caching Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, outputcache

More out of curiosity than anything. Do you think it'd be good practice to cache form pages?

I've got a form that has a dropdown box that is populated from a rather hefty SQL call and takes a bit too long to load (from my shared hosting site). It's a simple form that when submitted just saves a bit of data to the database.

I'm thinking I'll just cache the page using the OutputCache filter, but was wondering if there were any downsides to doing that?

Only logged in users can access the form. Would there be any issues with caching and different users accessing the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just cache the database results from the call. Does the form have any kind of validation? saving of current values?

Comment: I already do that... I throw the results of the data call into a Cache[] object. However, it would be much simpler to simply use OuputCache for this simple use. There are no saving of current values or anything like that. Very simple really. Any problems to look out for when trying to OutputCache a form?

Comment: the only thing I could think of would be the showing of validation errors if the form even has that.